# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_subplot' when using matplotlib in ipython

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

Hi, I was trying some code from WesMckinney's python data analysis book in ipython environment,which is built in anaconda. When I typed the simple code like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-9-559e30a6412a>", line 1, in <module>
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_subplot'
```

An AttributeError arose, but it's weird since anaconda is surely installed with `matplotlib` module. So Any suggestion? thank you.

Comment: You forgot the brackets. It should be `fig = plt.figure()`. Otherwise, you assign *the function* to fig, not the resulting generated figure.

Comment: Thant works, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you don't have the open and close brackets (`()`) at the end of `plt.figure`, so you haven't actually created a figure, just assigned a handle `fig` to the `plt.figure` function. Instead, try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() #Here is your error


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
```

Comment: I have plt.figure() but this problem is still coming up for me